# Accidentally pasted a file on my main git directory

Tags: git

I was trying to move some files from a disk-on-key to my root folder.. and there was a simple file named "git" amongst the files to be copied.
My main git directory was also named "git".. which means I accidentally pasted this file over my main git directory!

I had some files in there that I updated just recently and need for a project due tomorrow.
Now, just before I did this stupid mistake, I used `git commit -a`, but didn't do a `git push` yet (another mistake...) so I don't have the recent updates, which are crucial.
Every time I try anything I get this error:

> fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory

Is there any way to restore the last commited files so I don't have to go over the last pushed version and re-write from there..? (I've done quite a lot of calculations since, and I don't remember everything, so this will be a serious problem...).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean .. =\
I'm very new to git (and still a noob with programming in general).
Could you be more specific please..?

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Which of the files aren't overwritten? The .git dir? The original files?

Comment: Which are "not" overwritten?

All I have left is what was in my main repo (in the git site online).

Sorry if I'm not using to correct names for everything.. I'm very new to git, and English isn't my mother-tongue..

Comment: If all your files and the .git directory has been overwritten, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

No Problem

If I am not wrong there is no .git directory in your local repo. Your old directory still contains the changes you made for the last commit which you didn't push, then follow these steps.

- Clone your git repo at somewhere other location
- Copy the files from your old directory except the .git to your new directory.
- After that `git status` in new directory will show you your last file changes which are not pushed yet, (and these are not committed yet too).
- `> git status` will give you the result in new directory.
- stage files and commit and push.

(Or if you are working alone in the repo)

- copy the `.git` directory from new to old directory.
- Do `git status`, `git commit`, `git push`

If your .git folder is gone, and the code changes are not there in physical file, I have to be sorry. You have to write them again

`.git` directory gone -> Not a problem.
Local code changes gone -> Big Problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean with "Copy the files from your old repo except the .git to your new location." ?

How do I do that, if the old directory is deleted entirely (doesn't even appear in the trash bin) ?

Comment: I am sorry buddy. Thats what i mentioned : Your old repo still contains the changes you made for the last commit which you didn't push, then follow those steps. I must have to say you have to write your code again. 

By any chance you have copied the `.git` folder of old directory to somewhere?

Comment: No, I was about to make a backup when this happened... 
So I don't have the last version of my files (if I did, this wouldn't really be a problem).

Comment: `.git` is a hidden folder. you are saying something like `git` as a file. I cannot really understand.

Comment: When I clone I first create a folder, and then clone my repo into that folder.

I accidentally lost that folder I've created to keep my repo in. I don't have the last version of the files in it, and it's not in the trash bin either. Is there no way to get it back..? :(

Comment: Sorry. Disk Recovery is the solution but by that time you will be able to write the same code.

Comment: Upvoted it as this is a good answer (but the question is hard to understand)